# FFMPEG and -crf on Android

Tags: android, python, ffmpeg

yesterday I managed to build a newer Version of FFMPEG for Android. I directly created a binary which allows me to invoke commands per commandline. I builded the Version using NDK r9d and the 4.8 linux_x86_x64 toolchain.

After including everything in my Application my goal was to execute the command for which I did the whole effort.

My goal is to run:

```
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

Running this command on the command line via python works absolutly fine. However, running this command on Android does not work.

1) I get the error that I have to add

```
-strict experimental
```

After reading FFMPEG docu I found out, that this is due to the libx264. However, I do not understand why I have not to add this comment in the Python version.

2) After adding the parameter above, I was able to convert the video. However, the result was horrible. The transcoded images were just some noisy blinking green stuff. Thus, I looked for the problem. The problem is the parameter:

```
-crf 0
```

Due to this parameter, the result was so horrible. However, if I change the parameter to

```
-crf 1
```

everything is working as expected. BUT: I really want a lossless encoding here. That was the reason for choosing -crf 0. Moreover, this parameter works fine in my python version.

Can anybody explain to me: 
 1) What are I'm doing wrong?
 2) How can I use -crf 0 on Android?

Best regards,
André

//Edit:
Requested Logoutput:

```
06-12 19:23:04.841: I/System.out(8983): Starting process
06-12 19:23:04.871: D/dalvikvm(8983): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 294K, 4% free 9260K/9592K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983): ffmpeg version N-63698-g22d1b24 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   built on Jun 11 2014 13:17:16 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=armv7-a --sysroot=/home/andre/Desktop/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --disable-avdevice --disable-decoder=h264_vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --prefix=build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -DANDROID -I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L../android-libs -Wl,-rpath-link,../android-libs' --extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libavformat    55. 42.100 / 55. 42.100
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
06-12 19:23:04.871: I/System.out(8983):   libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
06-12 19:23:04.881: I/System.out(8983):   libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/screen_recording.mp4':
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):   Metadata:
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     major_brand     : isom
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     minor_version   : 0
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     creation_time   : 2014-06-12 11:52:00
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):   Duration: 00:00:09.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 597 kb/s
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 593 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16, 34.07 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):     Metadata:
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983):       creation_time   : 2014-06-12 11:51:56
06-12 19:23:04.971: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] using SAR=1/1
06-12 19:23:04.981: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
06-12 19:23:04.991: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:2:0 8-bit
06-12 19:23:04.991: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] 64 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=0 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
06-12 19:23:04.991: I/System.out(8983): Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/screen_recording_out.mp4':
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):   Metadata:
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     major_brand     : isom
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     minor_version   : 0
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     encoder         : Lavf55.42.100
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 65536:65536 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):     Metadata:
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):       creation_time   : 2014-06-12 11:51:56
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):       encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libx264
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983): Stream mapping:
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983):   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
06-12 19:23:05.001: I/System.out(8983): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
06-12 19:23:05.662: I/System.out(8983): frame=   14 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      51kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=1789.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
06-12 19:23:06.022: I/System.out(8983): frame=   20 fps= 20 q=0.0 size=     127kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=2395.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=14    
06-12 19:23:06.602: I/System.out(8983): frame=   25 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=     195kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=2659.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=16    
06-12 19:23:07.103: I/System.out(8983): frame=   30 fps= 14 q=0.0 size=     262kB time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=2803.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=21    
06-12 19:23:07.674: I/System.out(8983): frame=   50 fps= 19 q=0.0 size=     276kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate=1575.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=35    
06-12 19:23:08.174: I/System.out(8983): frame=   70 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=     277kB time=00:00:02.10 bitrate=1079.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=35    
06-12 19:23:08.725: I/System.out(8983): frame=   90 fps= 24 q=0.0 size=     278kB time=00:00:02.76 bitrate= 821.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=35    
06-12 19:23:09.245: I/System.out(8983): frame=  109 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=     291kB time=00:00:03.40 bitrate= 700.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=42    
06-12 19:23:09.746: I/System.out(8983): frame=  125 fps= 27 q=0.0 size=     299kB time=00:00:03.93 bitrate= 622.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=43    
06-12 19:23:10.236: I/System.out(8983): frame=  144 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=     300kB time=00:00:04.56 bitrate= 537.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=44    
06-12 19:23:11.117: I/System.out(8983): frame=  160 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=     337kB time=00:00:05.10 bitrate= 542.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=55    
06-12 19:23:11.277: I/System.out(8983): frame=  162 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=     378kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate= 598.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=58    
06-12 19:23:11.828: I/System.out(8983): frame=  178 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=     428kB time=00:00:05.70 bitrate= 614.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=59    
06-12 19:23:12.318: I/System.out(8983): frame=  198 fps= 27 q=0.0 size=     429kB time=00:00:06.36 bitrate= 551.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=68    
06-12 19:23:12.829: I/System.out(8983): frame=  214 fps= 27 q=0.0 size=     431kB time=00:00:06.90 bitrate= 511.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=69    
06-12 19:23:13.339: I/System.out(8983): frame=  233 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=     432kB time=00:00:07.53 bitrate= 469.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=70    
06-12 19:23:14.690: I/System.out(8983): frame=  262 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=     457kB time=00:00:08.73 bitrate= 428.4kbits/s dup=18 drop=76    
06-12 19:23:14.690: I/System.out(8983): video:455kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.401494%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] frame I:2     Avg QP: 0.00  size: 11390
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] frame P:260   Avg QP: 0.00  size:  1702
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] mb I  I16..4: 97.5%  0.2%  2.3%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] mb P  I16..4:  5.9%  0.3%  0.1%  P16..4:  0.9%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:92.8%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] 8x8 transform intra:3.6% inter:31.8%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 17.3% 9.6% 9.2% inter: 0.4% 0.3% 0.3%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] i16 v,h,dc,p: 69% 30%  1%  0%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 49% 29%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 31% 14%  1%  2%  2%  2%  1%  1%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] i8c dc,h,v,p: 80% 16%  3%  0%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.4% UV:4.6%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] ref P L0: 74.9%  4.1% 19.6%  1.3%  0.0%
06-12 19:23:14.710: I/System.out(8983): [libx264 @ 0x171c930] kb/s:426.18
06-12 19:23:14.740: I/System.out(8983): Finished
06-12 19:23:14.740: I/System.out(8983): Finished Process
```

Comment: Without your actual `ffmpeg` commands and the complete console outputs it will be hard to completely understand what may be occurring.

Comment: There is no other ffmpeg command. I just run the command mentioned above ('ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4') I add the logoutput above.